# If the following encrypt/decrypt code is used, would decompiling the code enable decryption?

Tags: encryption, vb6, cryptography, decompiling

```
Option Explicit 

Dim sSecretData
sSecretData = "Here is some very secret data." 

' Build up the key
Dim wshNetwork, sComputerName
Set wshNetwork = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Network") 
sComputerName = wshNetwork.ComputerName

Dim capEData
Set capEData = CreateObject("CAPICOM.EncryptedData")

capEData.Algorithm = 3 'Use 3DES
capEData.SetSecret sComputerName 
capEData.Content = sSecretData

Dim sCipherText
sCipherText = capEData.Encrypt

capEData.Algorithm = 3
capEData.SetSecret sComputerName 
capEData.Decrypt sCipherText

Dim sPlainText
sPlainText = capEData.Content 

MsgBox "Original data: " & sSecretData & chr(13) _ 
  & "Encrypted data: " & sCipherText & chr(13) _ 
  & "Recoverd data: " & sPlainText
```

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to implement some sort of DRM system. The first law of DRM is that it doesn't work: If your user's computer can decode the data, then your user can obtain the data for themselves.

Answer (score 4):

this one is even simpler: The key is just the computer name, the algorithm is well-known. So everyone, who can find out your computer name (this includes everyone on the same switch, even if his PC is compromised, and depending on your mail system everyone you ever sent mail to) can decrypt without limits.

If your PC crashed, and you gave your new installation a different name, you'd be out of luck also.

**Edit**

As from discussion: Having a **hardcoded** key, having a **decompiler** and having a **secret** key at the same time is impossible.

Your approach (use something, that differs from computer to computer) is quite OK, but you should rely on something, that can not so easily be read as the computer name (or MAC address ...). Processor serial number or windows product ID come to mind - both can not easily be read remote, but keep in mind, that it is game over, if somebody has access to this machine!

Comment: What can I use for a 'key' if I need to have this in the code and make it secret?